Product topology as disjoint union of base topologies in $\mathsf{Set}$
I was trying to understand the product topology today and I came up with a different perspective on it that I wanted to ask about.
Set-up: Consider the contravariant forgetful functor $U:\mathsf{Top} \rightarrow \mathsf{Set}$ sending $\big( (X,T_x) \rightarrow_f (Y,T_y) \in \mathsf{Top} \big) \mapsto \big( T_y \rightarrow_{f^{-1}} T_x \big)$. Let the image, $U(\mathsf{Top}) =: \mathsf{TopSet}$, be the image of this functor. Because this functor is injective, we have that $\mathsf{TopSet}$ is indeed a category, with objects as sets of open sets, which are closed under the usual topology axioms, and morphisms as functions between such sets.
Now, given $(X_a,T_a)_{a \in A} \subset \mathsf{Top}$, this sends their product space with the product topology, $(\prod_{a} X_a,T_{\prod})$ to the product topology $T_{\prod}$.
I believe that $T_{\prod}$ satisfies the following universal property in $\mathsf{TopSet}$:
Claim: Given a fixed $T \in \mathsf{TopSet}$ and maps $(g_a:T_a \rightarrow T)_{a \in A}$, $\exists! g:T_{\prod} \rightarrow T$ such that the following diagram commutes.
Pf) Let $Z$ be the maximal element of $T$ under inclusion, which exists since $T$ satisfies the topology axioms (this works because $T$ still contains the original space, which is this maximal element, that $U$ forgets). Then, because $\mathsf{TopSet}$ is the image of $U$, we have that the left-diagram in $\mathsf{Top}$ lies above the right diagram in $\mathsf{TopSet}$:

By the universal property of the product topology, there is a unique arrow $(Z,T) \rightarrow (\prod_{a} X_a, T_{\prod})$ making the left diagram commute. But the action of the functor preserves commutativity, implying the diagram lying below in $\mathsf{TopSet}$ also commutes. Uniqueness also follows with this correspondence.
Finally, the above is exactly saying that $T_{\prod}$ satisfies universal property of the disjoint union wrt. $(T_a)_{a \in A}$ in the category $\mathsf{TopSet}$. Thus, it is isomorphic to the disjoint union,
Intuitively, I think this rigorizes the perspective that the product topology is the most efficient `coming together' of the original topologies.
Question: Is the above sound? If so, because I haven't seen this perspective before, I'm curious if something like it is mentioned elsewhere in this or a related form, or whether something more useful/intuitive can be said here.

"which I believe satisfies the universal property of the disjoint union $\coprod T_a$" No, and you should have no trouble convincing yourself this is false (for a start, the disjoint union of topologies does generally not yield a topology).

Ah right, it is not true in general, but if we restrict to the subcategory of $\mathsf{Set}$ that is the image of this functor, then it is true (which I think is fine, since this is precisely the subcategory whose objects are topologies of some space).

I have no idea how you arrive at a disjoint union.

Maybe you are looking for the coproduct in the category of frames. But even that is not quite correct: you need some assumption on the topologies to conclude that the product topology is exactly the frame coproduct (rather than some quotient thereof).

@MartinBrandenburg I've added a more detailed argument about my process.

@ZhenLin I've added more details to it, and I'm unable to see where I might be incorrect.

The proof is incorrect: In the uniqueness part, your reasoning is that you take another morphism which makes the diagram in $\mathsf{TopSet}$ commute, and find in $\mathsf{Top}$ a preimage of this morphism by $U$, but there is no reason for the diagram you obtain in $\mathsf{Top}$ to commute, because $U$ is not faithful — e.g., if $Y$ has the trivial topology, then all maps $X → Y$ are continuous, and they are all sent by $U$ to the same map $∅ ↦ ∅, Y → X$.
Furthermore, the sort of result that you thought you proved would not yield much interesting, because coproducts in a subcategory of $\mathsf{Set}$ need not look anything like coproducts in $\mathsf{Set}$ (i.e. direct sums of sets). For example, the coproduct of groups is the free product, which is much more complicated than a direct sum (even for its underlying set: the free group of two finite groups is infinite, as long as the groups are non-trivial).
In fact there is no reason to try this almost-but-not-quite-dualization in the first place: The category $\mathsf{Top}$ is already a subcategory of $\mathsf{Set}$, and products exist in $\mathsf{Set}$, but this alone does not help much with understanding the products in $\mathsf{Top}$.

$\mathbf{Grp}$ is not a subcategory of $\mathbf{Set}$. Neither is $\mathbf{Top}$.

OK, it is isomorphic to a subcategory if you want. But it is common to say e.g. that $ℤ/2ℤ$ is a "subgroup" of $(10)$.

That’s not the point. There is not a common agreement on what a subcategory should be, abstractly, but in any case having a faithful functor is not enough.

You can map each group to its underlying set with an extra point added to remember the original group. We can distinguish this point from the others, say, build a set with the original group and sufficiently many elements with larger cardinal, to distinguish them from the group, such that this big set has larger cardinal than all the group elements. Map morphisms by mapping extra points to extra points. This gives a faithful and injective functor $\mathsf{Grp} → \mathsf{Set}$, so I think $\mathsf{Grp}$ in fact is isomorphic to a subcategory of $\mathsf{Set}$. Or am I going wrong somewhere?

Martin will no doubt say that it is nonsense to speak of objects in category being equal, and therefore it is nonsense to speak of functors being injective on objects. I would not put it so strongly but I am sympathetic to the idea, because I too find it ... unnatural ... to say that e.g. $\textbf{Grp}$ or even more so $\textbf{Top}$ is a subcategory of $\textbf{Set}$. So I am more inclined to define subcategories to identify them with functors that are faithful (on morphisms) and fully faithful on isomorphisms.
